# Scala: How to call a polymorphic, generic function

Tags: scala, functional-programming, polymorphism

I have the following code

```
def findFirst[A](as: Array[A], p: A => Boolean): Int = {
  def loop(n: Int): Int =
    if (n >= as.length) -1
    else if (p(as(n))) n
    else loop(n+1)
  loop(0)
}

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val as = Array("foo", "bar", "zed")
}
```

I don't understand how to call the function *findFirst* in the main method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code does not compile, there is no final `else` after the `else if`.

Comment: There are at least 4 syntax errors in this code. Obviously, you will not be able to call it if it cannot even be parsed. Once you fix the syntax errors, I see no problem with your code.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that i missed all the code! I have changed it now

Comment: What is `==>`? Should it be `=>`?

Comment: @DmytroMitin Yes, it was supposed to be `=>`. I have changed it now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The function takes two parameters, an array and a "predicate" (a function that takes a single argument itself and returns a boolean).

As such, `findFirst` is a higher-order function (it takes other functions as parameters or returns functions).

You can call it for example like this

```
 def isPrime(n: Int): Boolean = ??? // implement some code to return true for prime numbers
 findFirst(Array(1,2,3,4,5), isPrime)
```

or (using an anonymous, inline function)

```
 findFirst(Array("x", "ab", "abc"), x => x.length > 1 )
```

As you point out, `findFirst` is a generic function with a variable type `A`. Usually (as in the examples above, the compiler can infer the type you want `A` to be from the function parameters).

If it cannot, you can be explicit:

```
findFirst[Int](Array(), isPrime)
```